# Device.NET logger factory

Tags: c#

I'm using [Device.Net](https://christianfindlay.com/2021/01/31/device-net-4/) and am having trouble with ILoggerFactor. I have an Error that says 'LogLevel Exsists in both Device.Net and Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstracts' and 'ILoggerbuilder does not have a definition for AddDebug'. I am lost as to how to fix these complications.

```
var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create((builder) =>
            {
                _ = builder.AddDebug().SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
            });
```

Comment: You can qualify the LogLevel explicitly with the library name - something like `Device.Net.LogLevel.Trace`

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had the same problem and I solved it. You have to modify windows sample. You can do that with Nuget Packet Manager, you have to download Microsoft Extensions packets like Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, Microsoft.Extensions.Log.Debug etc... on nuget packet manager  .